# Oracle to SQL Server ODBC link - Invalid identifier when using WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle11g, database-link

I need to query data from SQL Server in Oracle using an ODBC database link.
I have created the necessary configuration in Oracle to allow me to access the SQL Server database and query the data.

When I do:

```
select * from table@ODBC_LINK
```

i get all rows returned.

When I do:

```
select * from table@ODBC_LINK WHERE [Field] = 'Some Value'
```

I get an

> ORA-000904 error; "Field" invalid identifier.

The field name is a valid field in the SQL-source database/table but it does not matter what I do, I am unable to use a WHERE clause as this always gives me the same ORA-error.

Using Oracle XE 11g and SQL Server 2012.

What is causing my problem?

Comment: Oracle doesn't use brackets to escape names like SQL Server does. Omit them, or use double quotes if your names might contain special characters.

Comment: Uhm, `Oracle XE 11g SQL = SQL Server 2012` ? Nope!

Comment: @der_roedie - tag the correct database here.

Comment: Tags are editted

Comment: @der_roedie . . . There was no need to edit the tags.  The commenter obviously didn't read the question, because you are using two different database products.

Comment: How does the column heading for Field look in the results, *exactly*, when you do the successful query without the `WHERE` clause? I'm wondering if there's some case-sensitivity going on as well as the other possible issues. Mixing Oracle, ODBC and SQL Server may well give some slightly odd restrictions and translations along the way... (And does `SELECT Field FROM table@ODBC_LINK` work?)

Comment: @MattGibson; as long as I do not use a where clause I get results returned but when ever I enter a where clause the error is shown. I have checked for case-sensitivity and notation of the field names in the select part; this only works when i type `select "Field" from table@ODBC_LINK'. When I leave the qoutes away I get the same error when I add the quotes in the select and add a where the error appears again. If I add the Quotes to the where clause aswell, still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is being run in *Oracle* not *SQL Server*.  The table comes from SQL Server, but not the parser.

So, first try no escape characters:

```
select * from table@ODBC_LINK WHERE Field = 'Some Value'
```

If you need to escape the name, use the *Oracle* escape character:

```
select * from table@ODBC_LINK WHERE "Field" = 'Some Value'
```

Comment: Hi Gordon,

first query results in ORA-000904.

Second query gives:
<code>ORA-02070: database QACOMMENTS does not support some function in this context
02070. 00000 -  "database %s%s does not support %s in this context"
*Cause:    The remote database does not support the named capability in
           the context in which it is used.
*Action:   Simplify the SQL statement.
Error at Line: 7 Column: 53</code>

Comment: sorry for the formatting..... SO-n00b for posting questions and comments :)

Comment: @der_roedie . . . Does the query work when run natively on the remote server?

Comment: Yes it does, no problems there.

I have another database link on the Oracle XE host that uses ODBC to a different instance on the same SQL server that is working fine with select-queries and WHERE clauses...

Thats whats driving me up the wall.

Comment: @der_roedie . . . What if you use a subquery?  `select * from (select . . . ) x where field = . . . `.

Comment: Tried: 
`select * from (select * from table@ODBC_LINK) x where x.field='some value'`

This gives the same ORA-000904 error...

Comment: @der_roedie . . . I suspect there is something amiss about the field name -- some hidden character, case sensitivity, alternative character set.  I'm not sure, but 000904 is related to bad identifiers.  Perhaps the identifier is a reserved word in Oracle (or perhaps in SQL Server).

Comment: @Gorden Linoff; I changed the field name I use in the where clause in the underlying SQL-table but still no luck, so I think we can rule out special characters of reserverd identifiers.